# With powershell from TXT to XML

Tags: xml, powershell

with the following powershell script could I transfer TXT to Powershell.

Here the powershell Code:

```
    $file = 'D:\orders.txt'
$ausgabeordner = 'D:\Ausgabe'

gc $file | %{
    $cols = $_.split(";")
    [xml]$xml = @"
<?xml version=`"$($cols[0])`" encoding=`"$($cols[1])`"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="$($cols[2])" OrderDate="$($cols[3])">
    <Address Type="$($cols[4])">
        <Name>$($cols[5])</Name>
        <Street>$($cols[6])</Street>
        <City>$($cols[7])</City>
        <State>$($cols[8])</State>
        <Zip>$($cols[9])</Zip>
        <Country>$($cols[10])</Country>
    </Address>
    <Items/>
</PurchaseOrder>
"@
    $itemsnode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/PurchaseOrder/Items")
    0..((($cols.Count - 11)/5)-1) | %{
        $index = 11+($_*5)
        $itm = $xml.CreateElement("Item")
        $itm.SetAttribute("PartNumber",$cols[$index])

        $node = $Xml.CreateElement("ProductName")
        $node.innerText = $cols[$index+1]
        [void]$itm.AppendChild($node)
        $node = $Xml.CreateElement("Quantity")
        $node.innerText = $cols[$index+2]
        [void]$itm.AppendChild($node)
        $node = $Xml.CreateElement("Price")
        $node.innerText = $cols[$index+3]
        [void]$itm.AppendChild($node)
        $node = $Xml.CreateElement("Comment")
        $node.innerText = $cols[$index+4]
        [void]$itm.AppendChild($node)
        [void]$itemsnode.AppendChild($itm)
    }
    $xml.Save((join-path $ausgabeordner "Order_$($cols[2]).xml"))
}
```

This ist the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="12345" OrderDate="2020-09-25">
<Address Type="Shipping">
<Name>Max Muster</Name>
<Street>Beispielstraße 123</Street>
<City>Musterstadt</City>
<State>Muster-Bundesland</State>
<Zip>12345</Zip>
<Country>Musterland</Country>
</Address>
<Items>
<Item PartNumber="123456">
<ProductName>Beispielartikel</ProductName>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>149.95</Price>
<Comment>Beispielkommentar</Comment>
</Item>
<Item PartNumber="1234567">
<ProductName>Beispielartikel-1</ProductName>
<Quantity>5</Quantity>
<Price>119.95</Price>
<Comment>Beispielkommentar-1</Comment>
</Item>
</Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

But now I would like to change the xml file via powershell to the following:
( above the )

```
    <Item PartNumber="1234567">
    <ProductName>Beispielartikel-1</ProductName>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <Price>119.95</Price>
    <Comment>Beispielkommentar-1</Comment>
<Test xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Item>
```

Could someone help me how it works?

It looks like the colon is causing problems. But I can't say what exactly the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Here-Strings to build the xml as text, making for much easier code.
Also, I think that to use `xsi:nil` the parentnode needs to have this namespace included: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

I's a pitty you didn't show us the input file, because I think you could make the code better readable if you were to import it as semi-colon delimited CSV file with added column headers. This will save you all the indexing and you could then use human-readable property names.

Try

```
$file          = 'D:\orders.txt'
$ausgabeordner = 'D:\Ausgabe'

# create a template Here-String for the <Item> elements
$itemTemplate = @"
        <Item PartNumber="{0}">
        <ProductName>{1}</ProductName>
        <Quantity>{2}</Quantity>
        <Price>{3}</Price>
        <Comment>{4}</Comment>
        <Test xsi:nil="true"/>
        </Item>
"@

Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
    $cols = $_.Split(";")
    # collect an array of ,Item> elements
    $items = 0..((($cols.Count - 11)/5)-1) | ForEach-Object {
        # output an item node from the template with properties filled in 
        $index = 11+($_*5)
        $itemTemplate -f $cols[$index..($index + 4)]
        # or: $itemTemplate -f $cols[$index], $cols[$index+1], $cols[$index+2], $cols[$index+3], $cols[$index+4]
    }

    # Now, output the completed xml, again using a template
    $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $ausgabeordner -ChildPath "Order_$($cols[2]).xml"

@"
<?xml version=`"$($cols[0])`" encoding=`"$($cols[1])`"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="$($cols[2])" OrderDate="$($cols[3])">
    <Address Type="$($cols[4])">
        <Name>$($cols[5])</Name>
        <Street>$($cols[6])</Street>
        <City>$($cols[7])</City>
        <State>$($cols[8])</State>
        <Zip>$($cols[9])</Zip>
        <Country>$($cols[10])</Country>
    </Address>
    <Items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
$items
    </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
"@ | Set-Content -Path $outputFile -Encoding UTF8
}
```